# Fail to up interface wlan0 in ubuntu server 22.04 Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, raspberrypi, netplan

Im having issues after installing ubuntu server 22.04 on raspberry pi 4

The interface wlan0 is down.

After following the official tutorial from ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#3-wifi-or-ethernet), im unable to set the interface up.
I've configured network-config file and rebooted but it doesn't connect.
Also I've tried with:

```
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

But it refuses to set the interface up. There is nothing in syslog or dmesg.

Also, I've edited /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml with the example given and running netplan apply, but it shows me the following error:

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:12:1: Error in network definition: unknown key 'wifis'
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

I'm a bit new with netplan

I've edited the post to include the output of following commands: ip a && cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

.

```
# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml   

# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource. Changes
# to it will not persist acrossan instance reboot. To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
version: 2
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-point:
      "My SSID":
        password: "My Password"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ip a` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` There is obviously an error in the netplan file that needs to be fixed. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you @chili555 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your netplan file has numerous errors in format. I suggest:

```
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true   
  wifis:
    wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "My SSID":
        password: "My Password"
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation and spacing, so proofread carefully twice. There are many templates for netplan that you can follow in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Please be certain that you install wpa-supplicant:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! My mistake was to put the word wifis at the same level of network.

Comment: Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment on this but I do not have enough credits to do so.
However, with the answer provided, I believe the items listed after the wlan0 entry should be indented.  Using the code as shown produces an error regarding the indenting after wlan0.
I propose the following change:

```
network:   
  version: 2   
  renderer: networkd   
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true   
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "My SSID":
          password: "My Password"
```

Also, I found if using a hidden SSID, add 'hidden' after the SSID entry:
Example:

```
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "My SSID":
          hidden: true
          password: "My Password"
```