# MT7601U not working even after installing Linux modules extra in Ubuntu server 22.04.1 on raspberry pi 4

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, raspberrypi

I had this same problem before, but it was fixed after I installed linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1011-raspi

After 4 months or so, I just got a fresh install of Ubuntu server 22.04.1 on my raspberry pi 4, but the MT7601U usb wifi adapter isn’t working, even after I installed Linux modules extra

I tried `sudo modprobe`, and it output:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module mt7601u not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-1021-raspi`

The adapter is being recognized when I do `lsusb` but not when I do `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`

[Images of output of modprobe, ifconfig,lsusb etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l00rD.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried installing the linux-modules-extra for the current kernel?

Comment: The answer you got 5 months ago is still valid: https://askubuntu.com/a/1418061/1210606 .

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes i did, but it didn't worked

Comment: @ChanganAuto but the thing is, i have already installed the Linux modules extra, but even after that it's still not working